# C++0x threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, c++11

With the advent of threading facilities in the STL for the new C++ standard (C++0x), will it be better to change existing code that is using POSIX threading or even Windows threading to use STL threading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always hedge your bets... write your own simple threading API that is just featureful enough to do what your application needs to be done, and change your code to target your threading API only.  Then you can implement the internals of your custom threading API using Windows or Posix or STL or whatever, and change the implementation whenever you need to without having to touch your entire codebase each time.

By doing it that way, you could start with the STL implementation, and then if it turns out that e.g. Windows has a difficult-to-resolve problem using that, you could just include an alternate Windows-API implementation inside my_threading_api.cpp (inside of an #ifdef WIN32) and you'd be back in business.

Comment: This is what we have done. We have created our own "OS abstraction layer" with different backend implementations for POSIX, Windows, and some other RTOS's we use. We've also got classes for semaphores, mutexes, timers, etc. It's a very useful thing to have.

Answer (score 4):

A great deal will depend on how much you care about portability, and how much you're taking advantage of features your native API may provide that the standard library doesn't. The standard library threading is sufficiently similar to POSIX that (at least offhand) I can't think of much you'd gain by staying with POSIX (and due to the similarity, porting to use the standard library should usually be pretty easy).

Windows threading is enough different that you're more likely to run into something that will be non-trivial to port to using the standard library, and even at best porting will probably be non-trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Don't change unless you really need it. I assume that your existing code is working well.

Answer (score 2):

There's no telling how long it will be before the C++0x library features are commonly supported, so the answer might well depend on how tied to a particular compiler you might want to be.
You might also want to consider a framework or library that works on top of the native or C++0x library implementation, such as [Boost Threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/doc/html/threads.html) or the [Intel Threading Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) and let that library handle the details of whether it's using C++0x features or platform APIs.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

C++0x threading isn't widely supported yet (I think GCC implements it, but MSVC doesn't, and I don't know when they're planning to add that support, but I might suspect they consider it a low priority feature)

If your code works as it is, why change it?
For new C++ applications, and assuming compiler support, I'd go with C++0x threads, simply because they're standard, and it's a much nicer API than either Win32 or POSIX threads.